# Клике по нужному option?

Tags: jquery

нужно чтобы при клике на Украина 
(Обычная цена:
1599 руб.
Цена со скидкой:
3198 руб.) ---- скрывалось!
а чтобы при клике на Россия
(Обычная цена:
1798 грн.
Цена со скидкой:
899 грн.
) - ----

```html
  <!-- price 1 -->
  <div class="price">
   <div class="price1">
    <span>Обычная цена:</span>
    <div class="boxuan_1">1798 <span>грн.</span></div>
   </div>
   <div class="price2">
    <span>Цена со скидкой:</span>
    <div class="boxuan_2">899 <span>грн.</span></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- price 2 -->
  <div class="price_second">
   <div class="price1">
    <span>Обычная цена:</span>
    <div class="boxuan_1">1599  <span>руб.</span></div>
   </div>
   <div class="price2">
    <span>Цена со скидкой:</span>
    <div class="boxuan_2">3198  <span>руб.</span></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- price 2 -->


  <div class="input_box">
   <form>
    <select name="Страна">
     <option value="Страна">Страна </option>
     <option value="Украина " >Украина </option>
     <option value="Россия" >Россия</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Номер телефона">
    <button><a href="">Заказать сейчас</a></button>
   </form>
  </div>
```

это скрывалось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На jQuery выглядит так:

```
$('[name="Страна"]').on("change", function() {
  switch(this.value) {
    case 'Украина ': $('.price').hide(); break;
    case 'Россия': $('.price_second').hide(); break;
  }
});
```

Comment: немного некорректно...1 это должна быть в начале одна цена, а при клике на две области сразу - они скриваются

Comment: Так адаптируй под свой взгляд. Код скрывает, как написано в вопросе.